# How to reset kartik depdrop to initial state with initial data

Tags: yii2, kartik-v

i have a depdrop in my project like

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'neighborhood_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map($query,'id','placeWithCity'),
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Your Neighborhood','id'=>'select_place'],
])->label(false); ?>
```

And

```
<?=$form->field($model, 'building_id')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
    'data' =>ArrayHelper::map(Buildings::find()->all(),'id','buildingWithPlace'),
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select The Building','id'=>'select_building'],
    'type' => DepDrop::TYPE_SELECT2,
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'depends' => ['select_place'],
        'url'=>Url::to(['property-commercial-rent/buildings']),
        'loadingText' => 'Loading buildings ...',
    ]
])->label(false);?>
```

The second dropdown is depend on the first one.Initially they both have full list of data without any filtering.When i select a neighborhood in the first dropdown then the second populates with the building names under that neighborhood. Then i have a reset button like and has an action like

```
$( "#reset-location" ).click(function() {
  $(select_place).val('').trigger('change');
  $(select_building).val('').trigger('change');
});
```

And this click resetting the both select.BUt the problem is the building has only the items under the previously select neighborhood.I want the make it all like initial stage.How can i do this

Comment: What does it say if you do `$(select_building).depdrop('init');`, throws an error saying it's already initialised?

Comment: @Ravenous nothing changed

Comment: Can't test it now, but removing the options under building should do it. The building dropdown will be recomposed after the user selects a new place.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a reset button.  On the neighbourhood field allow clear, so it would be like this

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'neighborhood_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'data' => ArrayHelper::map($query,'id','placeWithCity'),
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Your Neighborhood','id'=>'select_place'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true
        ],
])->label(false); ?>
```

Then there will be a x in the field to clear it.